# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Cli 0.5.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, webassembly, blazor

I have visual studio 2017 and .net core 2.1 but still not able to make it run.

While I am creating project I got this error Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Cli 0.5.1 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0

[image]

Check the below Available .net core SDKs and Runtimes are

[image]

Comment: The error suggests that you're targeting .NET Core 2.0 instead of .NET Core 2.1 as you claim. Have a look at your .csproj file's `TargetFramework` element.

Comment: I have created my project in .net core 2.1 only

Answer (score 1):

As of version 0.5.0 the CLI package targets .NET Core 2.1 rather than .NET Core 2.0. You will have to update the `<TargetFramework>` element in your csproj file to `netcoreapp2.1` if you want to use this pacakge.

I wonder though, why would you take a dependency on this package? It is a global tool. You should probably include packages like `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Build`, `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser`, etc.

Comment: I have tried this too but getting different error now.. 
The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Standard 2.1.  Either target .NET Standard 2.0 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Standard 2.1.


I have installed 2.1.4 version but still same problem.

Comment: please check attached new screenshot on top.

Comment: @vijaysahu you should either target `netcoreapp2.1` or `netstandard2.0`. Please note that .NET **Core** is on version 2.1 and .NET **Standard** is on 2.0.